# Replacing end of path in a file (vi)

Tags: gvim

With vi:
I have a file with hundreds of these type of lines below.

```
icpu_subsystem/i_v_top/i_jpeg_unit/ijpeg_dp/dp_p_rf_64x14_C_goal/U833462/A2 \
icpu_subsystem/i_v_top_ebd/i_jpeg_unit/ijpeg_dp/U121/A \
icpu_subsystem/i_v_top_eee/i_jpeg_unit/ijpeg_dp/U121/S \
```

I want to get rid of the last two directories in all the lines.
So for example, the output I'm looking for is:

```
icpu_subsystem/i_v_top/i_jpeg_unit/ijpeg_dp/dp_p_rf_64x14_C_goal/
icpu_subsystem/i_v_top_ebd/i_jpeg_unit/ijpeg_dp/ 
icpu_subsystem/i_v_top_eee/i_jpeg_unit/ijpeg_dp/
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:gvim], but write `vi` several places in the question. Are you using a GUI version of Vim, or some other vi emulator that is more "vi-like"? IOW, what program are you actually using? Please [edit] to clarify

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this change. Perhaps using the `:s` command might be what would first come to mind, but writing a regexp to match the last two directory components might be a bit tricky.

I like to use the `:normal` command, to repeat a sequence of Normal-mode commands on each line. For this particular case, you can use:

```
:%normal $2T/D
```

Which will repeat that sequence on every line of the range (which in this case is `%` for the whole file.)

The individual Normal mode commands are:

- `$` to move to the last column of the line.
- `2T/` to move backwards until the second `/` and stop right after it (see help for the `f`, `F`, `t` and `T` commands to move to a character on the same line.)
- `D` to delete from that point to the end of the line.

The sequence accomplishes what you wanted.

One advantage of this approach is that you can try the sequence of commands on the first line (or a specific line of the block) and visually get feedback about what it's doing, which should help you come up with the sequence to pass to `:normal` that will work for your task. (Don't forget to undo the changes to the line where you're experimenting, if you intend to pass it again as a part of the range to `:normal`.)

Comment: Normal with a bang? :)

Comment: @Ben yes sure that's usually safer in plug-ins... But in interactive case, `:normal` is closer to typing the commands directly and works with mapping from plug-ins too. Also, I tend to shorten it to `:norm` when using it in practice (the least typing, the better), so saving the `!` also helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%s#[^/]*/[^/]*$##` which basically means:

```
%s           - substitute in all lines
#            - delimiter
[^/]*        - match anything but a `/`, as much as possible, 
/            - followed by a `/` followed by
[^/]*        - anything but a `/` as much as possible followed by
$            - End of line
##           - replace by nothing
```

This should work in plain old vi, it does not use anything vim-specific.